# What are the alternative ways to access ABAP CDS Views?

Tags: abap, cds, informatica-powerexchange

I am aware that access to ABAP CDS views is possible in Informatica 10.4 by using the SAP Netweaver. But we have only Informatica version 10.2 Hence the below question.

​Is it possible to access the ABAP CDS Views using anything other than the SAP Netweaver for Informatica Powerexchange. Is this method same (as in performance) as exposing the views as OData?

A quick Google search did not bring anything useful. I am aware that CDS views which are exposed as OData can be accessed by various libraries. Other than these options is there any alternative to accessing the ABAP CDS views using other libraries.

Are the ABAP CDS views accessible from HANA database? If so are there any library to connect to HANA from Java or Python or Informatica 10.2.

Edit [21-08]: Just came across this https://help.sap.com/viewer/f2e545608079437ab165c105649b89db/7.5.6/en-US/7c078765ec6d4e6b88b71bdaf8a2bd9f.html. I am not sure if it is part of Abap development tools?

Comment: There is HANA JDBC for Java https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.03/en-US/ff15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4.html

Comment: `exposed as OData can be accessed by various libraries. Other than these options is there any alternative to accessing the ABAP CDS views using other libraries` you do not these libraries and want another libraries. For what? The question is not clear

Comment: @suncatcher yes, I am trying to see if there are other options available. When I was searching today i came across this method. I believe it is part of Abap Development tools but i am not sure. https://help.sap.com/viewer/f2e545608079437ab165c105649b89db/7.5.6/en-US/7c078765ec6d4e6b88b71bdaf8a2bd9f.html.
Would the HANA JDBC driver have access to the Abap objects since these must be in the Abap application server?

Comment: The only SAP premium certified integration which has CDS view support: https://www.sap.com/dmc/exp/2013_09_adpd/enEN/#/solutions?id=s:eb0d78b1-cdaa-47b2-90d3-3791c13afae1